# Comparing Performance in Oracle

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

I would like to compare two SQL statements which produce the same result. For example

```sql
SELECT
    id, name,
    (SELECT street || ' ' || town from addresses WHERE addresses.id=customers.addressid) AS address
FROM customers;

--  vs

SELECT
    id, name,
    street || ' ' || town AS address
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN addresses a ON c.id=a.customerid;
```

Here I want to compare the performance of the subquery compared to using a join. I know about the other advantages and disadvantages of subqueries and joins, but I’m more interested in comparing their performance.

How can I do a performance comparison? Is there some sort of timing test?

Comment: Those two queries are doing different things. If you want to compare them, you need to use an outer join in the second query (`LEFT JOIN addresses a on ...`). I wouldn't be surprised if you will see identical execution plans for bot then

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good point. I’ll add that into the example. I wasn’t really interested in these particular queries, but how to compare them. However I certainly should make sure that the do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some sort of timing test?

Yes, in SQL*Plus, do it as

```
SQL> set timing on
```

and then run queries, each of them several times (to avoid caching issues) and compare time needed for each query to complete. Note that on small data sets you won't notice any difference, so - whichever you use, it'll be OK.

```
SQL> select e.deptno, (select d.dname from dept d where d.deptno = e.deptno) dname, e.ename
  2  from emp e
  3  where e.deptno = 20;

    DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME
---------- -------------- ----------
        20 RESEARCH       SMITH
        20 RESEARCH       JONES
        20 RESEARCH       SCOTT
        20 RESEARCH       ADAMS
        20 RESEARCH       FORD

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
SQL> select e.deptno, d.dname, e.ename
  2  from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  where e.deptno = 20;

    DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME
---------- -------------- ----------
        20 RESEARCH       SMITH
        20 RESEARCH       JONES
        20 RESEARCH       SCOTT
        20 RESEARCH       ADAMS
        20 RESEARCH       FORD

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
SQL>
```

Other than that, did you compare explain plans? Did you collect statistics on tables and indexes (and do it regularly)? Are there any indexes (should be on columns used in joins, most probably)?